# HttpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryWithoutValidation is automatically adding spaces

Tags: c#

When adding an `Accept` header to a HTTPClient it seems to automatically add spaces, which seems to be a problem for the web service that I am using. They expect a `Content-Length` of no more than 120. But, because of the spaces being added it's making it 131.

This is my current code:

```
client.DefaultRequestHeaders.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept", "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8");
```

It seems to add spaces as can be seen in Fiddler:

```
text/html, application/xhtml+xml, application/xml; q=0.9, image/webp, */*; q=0.8
```

I know in normal cases this shouldn't be a problem for the server, but in my case it is. when the request is sent from a browser, there are no spaces.

Edit: It also does the same for `Accept-Language` and `Accept-Encoding`

Comment: [This overload of TryAddWithoutValidation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh875106(v=vs.110).aspx) accepts an IEnumerable<string> - you could try sending the headers as a List<string>

Comment: The reason why I had to set it as a string is because I get an exception when trying to add '*/*; q=0.8'.

Comment: It's still adding spaces. Is there any alternative I can use?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and this worked for me :

```
httpRequestMessage.Headers.TryAddWithoutValidation("Accept","text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
```